# WCF Error 400 Bad Request when sending message bigger than 100mb

Tags: wcf, soap, web-config

I made my first WCF service where I'm receiving data I have to process. The problem occurs when I send larger amounts, a 100mb soap message, of data at once, I get the reply Error 400 Bad Request.

I tried setting maxReceivedMessageSize, maxBufferSize, maxAllowedContentLength, readerQuotas that are referenced in other questions, but nothing seems to work or just makes the service not work at all.

These are the current settings in my web.config

```
<services>
  <service name="RMQServices.RMQ_WS1" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint address="webHttp" contract="RMQServices.RMQService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBasic" />
    </service>
</services>

<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myBasic" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:30:00">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<requestFiltering>          
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
</requestFiltering>
```

Am I still missing something in the config for it to work and accept larger requests?

EDIT:
If I send data via a service reference then it accepts even 1GB soap messages. But if I try to send it via HttpWebRequest with a prebuilt SOAP XML, then it still returns a Bad Request. So the problem seems to be in how I send the data.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your client config also have these values

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="[address]" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBasic" contract="" name="Name" />
</client>
```

And then add

```
<bindings>


    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myBasic" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:30:00">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

if this does not work, remove the security from the binding and then validate

Comment: After further testing the client is at fault yes. If I add a service reference to the service it accepts anything. But when I send a prebuilt soap XML via HttpWebRequest it still returns a Bad Request.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the following code snippets.

```
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mybehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="3600" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Also, Don’t forget to apply the configuration between the client-side and server-side (you should also add this configuration on both the client-side and server-side endpoints).
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.